# Migrate to Bootstrap 5 - Video Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have a modal with video inside, written for Bootstrap 4. I want to migrate this to Bootstrap 5, where no jQuery is available. How may I do this? The problem is the JavaScript here:

```
  <script>
  // codepen.io/JacobLett/pen/xqpEYE
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var $videoSrc;
      $('.video-btn').click(function() {
          $videoSrc = $(this).data( "src" );
      });
      console.log($videoSrc);

      // when the modal is opened autoplay it
      $('#videoModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
          // set the video src to autoplay and not to show related video. Youtube related video is like a box of chocolates... you never know what you're gonna get
          $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc + "?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0" );
      })

      // stop playing the youtube video when I close the modal
      $('#videoModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
          // a poor man's stop video
          $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc);
      })
  });
  </script>
```

The modal is using

```
        <button type="button" class="video-btn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#videoModal" data-bs-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EzDC8aAJln0" >
            <img src="/img/video/dbschema-video.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="DbSchema Video Presentation">
        </button>

 <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dbschemaModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="video" allowscriptaccess="always" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you only want the Bootstrap parts to be converted to JS, or the entire code to JS?

Comment: Have you attempted the JS for yourself? I'm sure you know SO isn't a coding service. Please post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#via-javascript).

So you can do something like below:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var $videoSrc;
      document.querySelector('.video-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
          $videoSrc = $(this).data( "src" );
      });
      console.log($videoSrc);

      // when the modal is opened autoplay it
      document.getElementById('videoModal').addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
          // set the video src to autoplay and not to show related video. Youtube related video is like a box of chocolates... you never know what you're gonna get
          $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc + "?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0" );
      })

      // stop playing the youtube video when I close the modal
      document.getElementById('videoModal').addEventListener('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
          // a poor man's stop video
          $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc);
      })
  });
```

Also you should add `-bs-` to your data-attributes wherever you use bootstrap-5

Answer (score 1):

For vanilla JS it would be something like this...

```
var videoBtn = document.querySelector('.video-btn')
var videoModal = document.getElementById('videoModal')
var video = document.getElementById('video')
var videoSrc

videoBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    videoSrc = videoBtn.getAttribute('data-bs-src')
})

videoModal.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal',(e)=>{
    video.setAttribute('src', videoSrc + '?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0')
})

videoModal.addEventListener('hide.bs.modal',(e)=>{
    video.setAttribute('src', videoSrc)
})
```

Here's the [working code](https://www.codeply.com/p/2JVHI5LOqt)